# Prolog, access specific member of list?

Tags: list, prolog, unification

Can anyone tell me how to access a specific member of a list in prolog? Say for example I need to access the 3rd or 4th element of a list passed into a rule?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`nth0(Ind, Lst, Elem)` or `nth1(Ind, Lst, Elem)` with SWI-Prolog, `nth0` the first element has the index 0.

For example,

```
nth0(3, [a, b, c, d, e], Elem). %Binds d to Elem
nth1(3, [a, b, c, d, e], Elem). %Binds c to Elem

nth0(Ind, [a, b, c, d, e], d).  %Binds 3 to Ind
nth0(3, [a, b, c, X, e], d).    %Binds d to X

nth0(3, [a, b, c, d, e], c).    %Fails.
```

Comment: so if make a rule that needs to unify something with certain element of a list passed in, how would I use this?

Comment: Here are examples of use     ?- L = [a,b,c], nth0(Ind, L, a),nth0(2, L, X).    
    L = [a,b,c],    
    Ind = 0,    
    X = c .    
    
   or  ?- L = [a,b,c], nth1(Ind, L, a), nth1(2, L, X).    
    L = [a,b,c],    
    Ind = 1,    
    X = b .

Answer (score 6):

When the indexes you need to access are so small, you could use pattern matching. Say we need the third element or fourth:

```
third([_,_,E|_], E).
fourth([_,_,_,E|_], E).
```

This could be more useful if used 'inline', when the list carries info with positional relevance. For instance

```
your_rule([_,_,E|Rest], Accum, Result) :-
   Sum is Accum + E,
   your_rule(Rest, Sum, Result).
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A prolog list is a classic list. Access is not direct. You have to iterate over to to find what you need.

You can get the nth element this way:

```
foo( [X1,X2,X3,X4,...,XN|Xs] ) :- ...
```

where [code]X[/code]<sub>*n*</sub> is the *nth* element of the list. Impractical for *n* larger than a small value. This is roughly analogous to a C/C++ pointer expression:

```
LLNode *nthElement = root->next->...->next ;
```

Otherwise, you have to iterate over the list to find the desired element, using a built-in predicate or a home-brew predicate, something like:

foo(Xs) :- nth_element(Xs,9,X) , ...

nth_element(Xs,N,X) :- nth_element(Xs,0,N,X) .

nth_element([X|Xs],N,N,X) :- !.
   nth_element([_|Xs],T,N,X) :- T1 is T+1 , nth_element(Xs,T1,N,X).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`func`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=func) library for SWI-Prolog, it is possible to write list comprehensions in a more concise way:

```
:- use_module(library(func)).

nth0((Index, List), Result) :-
    nth0(Index,List,Result).
```

Now, you can access two elements of the list and add them together like this:

```
example :-
    List = [1,5,12,9],
    Y is (nth0 $ (0, List)) + (nth0 $(3,List)), %add the 1st and 4th elements of this list
    writeln(Y). %prints 10
```